# Ryzen 4000U Series failing to enter suspend/modern-standby correctly

Tags: suspend, amd-graphics, acer

Mobile computers (at least many models) with the Ryzen 4000U Series are failing to enter suspend/modern-standby correctly.
The device will not wake up from suspend/modern-standby. The keyboard lights in might be lit in some cases but the screen will not and there are no keys that can be pressed that will "wake it" up.

This bug is known for modern Acer Swift 3, Lenovo an HP devices, for example:

- Acer Swift 3 (SF314-42-R9YN)
- Acer Swift 3 (SF314-42-R2UX)
- Lenovo 14are05

Is this a known issue, are there workarounds to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is an apparently known, but yet unfixed kernel bug in `amdgpu`. See here: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/amd/-/issues/1230

It isn't even fixed in 5.12.

You could try to patch and compile the kernel with the patches mentioned int the thread above. Good luck!

For those who do not want to compile their own kernel or are not capable to, I attached patched and compiled kernel here:
https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/amd/-/issues/1230#note_902370

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [the link provided by user5950](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/amd/-/issues/1230), by the end of 2020 it was expected that [5.11 would have this problem solved](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=AMD-SoC-PMC-Driver-Linux-5.11), although [this might have not have happened](https://dev.to/epassaro/fix-suspend-issues-on-dell-7405-2-in-1-3l1b).
A workaroud is mentioned [here](https://www.walkswithme.net/lets-try-linux-on-amd-ryzen-4000-series-processors), YMMV.

I am not sure what is the current status.
Apparently, all roads lead to [Rome](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/amd/-/issues/1230).

**Related**

1. https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxhardware/comments/j517jj/amd_ryzen_7_4700u_suspendhibernate_not_working_on/
2. https://www.tuxedocomputers.com/en/Infos/Help-Support/Help-for-my-device/TUXEDO-Book-BA-series/TUXEDO-Book-BA15/Suspend-problems-on-devices-with-Ryzen-CPU.tuxedo

Comment: The workaround mentioned does not work on my device.

Comment: @user5950 - Ok, it might well be the case that you have to wait for the bug to be solved.

Answer (score 0):

There have been four posts today on: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/amd/-/issues/1230 which is the link posted by *user5950*.

Running Kernel 5.12.1 fixes the problem for the first suspend/resume but unless you reboot the second suspend/resume cycle crashes.

This indicates something was left unstable after the first resume and some drivers need to be reinitialized.

Released two days ago is an even newer kernel 5.12.2 which may improve the situation even more:

- [https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.12.2/](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/v5.12.2/)

For instructions on installing a mainline kernel published by Ubuntu:

- [How to update kernel to the latest mainline version without any Distro-upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/a/885165/307523)

Comment: Apparently the issue hasn't been fixed neither in 5.12.x nor in 5.13rc.

Comment: @user5950 It appears the happy middle ground is hibernation. AMD was never a keener at getting Linux to work. I've always recommend Dell, Intel, Brother, Nvidia, etc. that are quick to release Linux drivers. Indeed some of them actually help write some of linux. Look at Dell and DKMS for example.

Answer (score 0):

Many people say that kernel 5.14-rcX solves their amdgpu suspend issues, but not my. In addition to the 5.14 kernel, my HP 15s-eq1009 with Ryzen 3 4300U needed updating DSDT. [Here is my workaround.](https://askubuntu.com/a/1357421/830349)

And [here](https://dev.to/epassaro/fix-suspend-issues-on-dell-7405-2-in-1-3l1b) is the workaround for Dell 7405 which inspired me.